# PHP Image Intervention Library not working with image path passed from bash script

Tags: php, bash, intervention

I am using a call to `php-cli` in a bash script like

```
php /var/www/scripts/php_script.php "$OUTPUT"
```

where `$OUTPUT` is a bash variable. I get this argument of `$OUTPUT` variable as `$argv[1]` in PHP script.

```
$path = $argv[1];
```

I also did it another way:

```
$path = "/path/to/some/images.png";
```

I am using PHP Intervention Image Library to create an instance of the image file with path $path.

```
$image = Image::make($path);
```

The second way with string assigned works perfectly but there is no any output or error when using the first approach. The code flow exits at this line.
I tried `var_dump($path)`. Both of the approaches give the same result. What is the difference in using these two approaches?

Comment: try `var_dump` of `$image` or check server error log, also check file permission

Comment: the same image path when used in string assigned is working, so the file permission is correct. `var_dump` of `$image` is just showing nothing. The code execution stops in line with this code: `$image = Image::make($path);` . I have turned on error_reporting. There are no any errors displayed.

Comment: the code works for string without spaces but not for string with spaces.